# Offset multipoint force vector math formula to move an object (barge on water)

Tags: vectors

I have a rectangular 1000kg barge on still water and no wind with center of mass C.

I can apply force at corners A and B only.

How much and at what direction should force be applied at points A and B to move the barge sideways in the direction of the arrow?

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you,
Gil

[Vector math setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIDdU.jpg)

Comment: Please show any work you may have done.

Comment: I added a diagram but I have no idea where to start solving this problem.  My last experience with vector math was decades ago.

Comment: Have you done any research into it? People here get really cranky if you ask questions without googling relevant concepts first and showing you've put in some effort.

Comment: I've spent a few weeks looking at vector math formulas and solutions on-line.  Trying to determine what the solution is.  I finally decided to reach out to a community to see if someone had any guidance or could point me in the right direction.